# Long notes after stop AKSequencer

Tags: audiokit

Sometimes I need some long notes to keep playing after the sequencer stops.

```
akSequencer.stop() // Need to put some code to ask the question
```

Is there any way to keep the sound of a long note when AKSequencer stops?

Comment: This would be more like a "pause sequencing" (instead of stop) where no note-off events are sent. AFAIK this is not yet in AKSequencer and I'd use it too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of connecting your AKMusicTrack's MIDI output directly to your sampler (or oscillator bank or whatever), send it to an `AKCallbackInstrument`.  In the callback function, you can check the status of the sequencer's MIDI messages, and send your the noteOn and noteOff messages to your sampler from there.  In the callback you can add conditional logic, for example, you could use some flag to ignore the noteOff messages under certain conditions.

For the record, this is how I always set up my sequencers, since you can control not only to your sampler, but also external MIDI, Audiobus MIDI and so on, as well as UI updates, from the same AKMusicTrack using a callback.

```
var seq = AKSequencer()
var sampler = AKAppleSampler()
var callbackInst: AKCallbackInstrument!
var track: AKMusicTrack!
var allowNoteOff: Bool = true

func setupSequencerCallback() {
    track = seq.newTrack()
    callbackInst = AKCallbackInstrument()
    track.setMIDIOutput(callbackInst.midiIn)
    callbackInst.callback = { status, note, vel in
        switch status {
        case .noteOn:
            try? self.sampler.play(noteNumber: note, velocity: vel, channel: 0)
        case .noteOff:
            if self.allowNoteOff {
                try? self.sampler.stop(noteNumber: note, channel: 0)
            }
        default:
            return
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks c_booth, interesting. Never used AKCallbackInstrument ... Any sample code ?

Comment: I'm using timers to throw functions at beats / loop repeat. It's possible to call them from  AKCallbackInstrument ?

Comment: Added some code.   Definitely AKCallbackInstrument is what you want to use for triggering code based on your sequencer's position or behaviour.

Comment: Just testing your setup, it's much better. With AkSequencer, the first beat was playing few ms late. With callback seems more accurate

Comment: c_booth, To throw function each beat, Do I need to make a track with quarter notes or  there's another direct way ?

Comment: Yeah, you basically need to add a track of quarter notes if you want it to call the functions on each beat.

Comment: Does AKAppleSampler perform pitch bend ?